# Items in ng-options not updating to selected language

Tags: angularjs

My issue is that the options in my dropdown menus are not changing to the correct language. 
For example if I go from English to Chinese everything else will update just fine, but the items in the drop down won't until after I select one of the options in the list, then it will change to the appropriate language. However, all of the other dropdown menus will remain untranslated until they are interacted with like the first one. Is there some way for me to force them to update after I change what language it's being displayed in?

Here's an example of one of the dropdown menus

```
<label class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                <span translate="chart"></span>
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="report.chart" ng-options="c | translate for c in charts" ng-change="setChartType(report)">
                </select>
</label>
```